# Запятая при однородных придаточных

Tags: спп, однородные-члены, придаточное-предложение

Являются ли придаточные в данном предложении однородными, и нужно ли ставить запятую между ними?

Это был наш сосед, который каждый вечер прибирал в подъезде(,) и чей голос невозможно было ни с чем спутать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это был наш сосед, который каждый вечер прибирал в подъезде и чей голос невозможно было ни с чем спутать.

Это СПП с однородными **определительными** придаточными, отнесенными к сущ. "сосед", союзные слова КОТОРЫЙ и ЧЕЙ, запятая при наличии одиночного союза И не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос. Я думаю, что да, придаточные можно считать однородными, но запятая не нужна. Оба придаточный относятся к одному слову, и, хотя формально к ним ставятся разные вопросы ("который" и "чей"), оба характеризуют соседа, а не голос.